# Spark worker node cannot start. Incorrect java path in logs

Tags: apache-spark, java-home

I am trying to run the spark with one worker node. Master node is correctly started and WebUI is also accessible. But Slave or worker node cannot be started due to error.

```
<SparkPath>/sbin$ ./start-slaves.sh 
localhost: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /home/ashish/KeplerData/workflows/module/spark-1.1.0/tools/sbin/../logs/spark-ashish-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-ashish-VPCEB34EN.out
localhost: failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker:
localhost:   /home/ashish/KeplerData/workflows/module/spark-1.1.0/tools/sbin/../bin/spark-class: line 76: **/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/bin/java: No such file or directory**
localhost: full log in /home/ashish/KeplerData/workflows/module/spark-1.1.0/tools/sbin/../logs/spark-ashish-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-ashish-VPCEB34EN.out
```

Slaves.sh

> localhost

Java Configuration:

```
$ tail -f /etc/profile
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH


$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

Is there any other file in which I have to set the JAVA_HOME path ?
Thanks.

Comment: change `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH` to `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH`

Answer (score 1):

You should define in `/spark_home/conf/spark-env.sh` below line:

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle`